# Overflow:scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have created a webpage with a floating/fixed panel that slides up from the bottom of the page. Inside this pane is a child div which has content that needs to be scrolled, I have set the `overflow` to `scroll` and `auto` but none seem to do the trick. It should be noted I'm using easytabs.js plugin to switch content inside the panel, I believe this could be the reason its not working as expected.

You can find a link to the page [here](http://mogulindiancuisine.co.uk/#specials-tab)

Could anyone have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The relevant CSS is below

```
#menu-tab {
    display: block;
    /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);*/
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#menu-content {
    display: none;
    /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);*/
    background: #fff;
    color: #111;
    /*padding: 30px 0;*/
    height: 1px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

/* Styles for Tabs on Side */
#tab-side-container { padding: 50px 0; }
#tab-side-container > ul { list-style: none; margin: 0 40px 0 0; padding: 5px 0; background: #f1f1f1; float: left; }
#tab-side-container > ul li { width: 200px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: right; font-size: 28px; text-transform: uppercase; }
#tab-side-container > ul li a { display: block; padding: 11px 15px; outline: none; color: #000; }
#tab-side-container > ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
#tab-side-container > ul li.selected-tab { background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); position: relative; left: 1px; }
#tab-side-container > ul li:first-child.selected-tab { border-top: none; }
#tab-side-container > ul li a.selected-tab { text-decoration: none; }
#tab-side-container .panel-container { padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 240px; }

div.menu {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Change your #menu-content css overflow to auto or scroll.

Comment: After Bobby's answer, get rid of the default scroll with Nice Scroll.

Comment: @Bobby I cant believe I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: @Dznr Thanks this is a very nice plugin

Comment: This is a messy solution; there are other issues too, if you take a look at my answer I fixed them.

Answer (score 2):

Buddy, i check your website, the problem is not in the CSS File, the problem is in the jQuery plugin named isotope, the isotope inject this code:

```
   overflow: hidden;
```

as a style attribute at the .menu class, So you need to configure the plugin properly.

you can try, replacing this code:

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.menu div',
    animationEngine: 'css'
});
```

For this code:

```
 $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.menu div',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    containerStyle: {
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'auto'
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One way you could deal with the problem is by setting height: 100% for div "tab-side-container", div "panel-container" and div "specials-tab". You'll also need to set "overflow:scroll" on "specials-tab". You may also need to set the "specials-tab" child div to height:100%.

That works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Your on the right path here, a scroll bar is now shown.. but the div below the fold is still not shown.. its as if its cut off.. if you look through Chrome inspector you will see a fourth div that should be shown.

Comment: Ahh, that tricked me for a minute -- at first I wanted to just set menu-tab to height 100%, but it breaks your interface. Try setting height: 100% on the child div that is cut off. That should correctly serve the Masala. In general you need to be careful that div have the correct height -- there's lots of things that can cause them to collapse, which can mess up layout. Nice looking website, BTW.

Comment: Thanks! I've altered formatting of the last div a little bit, it shows up in the correct place so its visible now. I think this has more to do with the `#menu-content` or `#tab-side-container`. One of the indications for this is that even the scroll bar is cut off at the bottom on my browser. The issue occurs on both Chrome and Safari for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the content of the div has to exceed the size of the div in order for an overflow:scroll to work. Either make the content bigger or make the div smaller and see if that works for you.
 Also, "overflow:auto" on a div will set it to scroll only vertically, whereas "overflow:scroll" will set it to scroll both vertically and horizontally. Just a side note.

Comment: The content _does_ exceed the div, hence why you cant see it. Its because its not on the next line which may lead you to believe the content has finished.

Comment: `overflow: auto` will scroll a `div` (or any other element) in both directions **if** there is overflow there.

Answer (score 0):

just change `specials-tab height(less then 860px)` and also give `specials-tab` to

```
overflow:scroll;
```

you can also set these properties to it's child if you want to scroll left and right div separately

Answer (score 0):

please add to css property in your css

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

[enter link description here](http://trustedwebscripthelp.blogspot.com)also check from here for website problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Either **#menu-content{overflow:auto}** or **#menu-content{overflow:scroll}**

Answer (score 0):

**Working jsbin:** (I cloned your site in jsbin to show example of it working)
http://jsbin.com/eWoXUHe/1

---

**DETAILS:**

Overflow scrolls automatically by default. however, if the div is not taller than the window (or containing div) height, then there is nothing to scroll, so it won't scroll. If you want to scroll anyway then just make the div taller than the window (or containing div) height.

From reviewing your website, I noticed immediately that `.specials-tab` is 1080px high. Because of this, that div extends far below the bottom of the page. You need to make this containing div smaller, for example 500px.

After you make that containing div height smaller, you can then scroll the inside content. You may also need to add `overflow: scroll` to the inner div (it will work once you made the outer div height smaller).

---

**SOLUTION:**

The following code will fix your site:

```
.specials-tab, #starters-tab, #specials-tab, #main-dishes-tab, #sides-tab, #sundries-tab, #drinks-tab, #desserts-tab {
  height: 300px !important;
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

---

**NOTES:**

- Don't use `!important`. Instead add `height: 300px; overflow: scroll;` manually to each of the above elements. I put `!important` so you could see it working in the jsbin.
- I put 300px just so it was small enough for you to see it working. However you can make this 500px or whatever pixel you want.

Comment: This limits the size of the content to a fixed height (in your example 300px), the content should fill the whole y length (dynamic).

Comment: You could make it dynamic just fine. It's not hard to do, and it's not limited to a fixed height. Try using a percentage instead. Percentage works fine too.

Answer (score -1):

You could change your css to something like the below:

```
    #parent {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    }
    #box1 {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    }
    #box2 {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    }
```

I think this achieves what you're asking.